# Azure Data Factory convert Json Column into multiples column - Flatten

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Hi I ended up with this two columns in a pipeline with data flow. Each row has an id and json related with money's transactions. This json can contents multiples transactions and each transaction has the following fields: currency, amount, date and commerce

| Id | jsonTransactions |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | [{"fields":[{"name":"Currency","value":"USD","type":"String"},{"name":"Amount","value":"50.00","type":"Double"},{"name":"Date","value":"24/04/2020","type":"Date"},{"name":"Commerce","value":"Addidas","type":"String"}]},{"fields":[{"name":"Currency","value":"USD","type":"String"},{"name":"Amount","value":"65.50","type":"Double"},{"name":"Date","value":"25/04/2020","type":"Date"},{"name":"Commerce","value":"Amazon","type":"String"}]}] |
| 4213 | [{"fields":[{"name":"Currency","value":"USD","type":"String"},{"name":"Amount","value":"45.00","type":"Double"},{"name":"Date","value":"26/04/2020","type":"Date"},{"name":"Commerce","value":"Apple","type":"String"}]},{"fields":[{"name":"Currency","value":"USD","type":"String"},{"name":"Amount","value":"54.50","type":"Double"},{"name":"Date","value":"27/04/2020","type":"Date"},{"name":"Commerce","value":"Burger King","type":"String"}]}] |

[image]
**And Im trying to get this result:**

| Id | Currency | Amount | Store | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | USD | 50.00 | Addidas | 24/04/2020 |
| 1234 | USD | 65.50 | Amazon | 25/04/2020 |
| 4213 | USD | 45.00 | Apple | 26/04/2020 |
| 4213 | USD | 54.50 | Burger King | 27/04/2020 |

**I've tried to use Flatten's Unroll By option but couldnt select the json column. I think its because it doesnt recognize the column as json object but as a string.**

[image]

***Data Types
[image]

Comment: what is the format of your row data, is it Json?

Comment: hi @SallyDabbah, "id" column is long and "jsonTransactions" is string.

Comment: You need to turn the jsonTransactions column into a JSON object. Use the Parse transformation to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-parse